# Почему одинаковые программы на Python и Java работают по разному (или почти одинаковые)?

Tags: java, python, алгоритм

Вы, наверное, посчитаете этот вопрос глупым, но все же...

Есть два алгоритма на **Python** и **Java**, делающие одинаковые вещи и написание *почти* один в один, но при [проверке](https://algotester.com/en/ArchiveProblem/Display/29) (если интересно что код делает, то почитайте в Statement) алгоритм на Java проходит все отлично, а на Python видает ошибку **Time Limit**

### Код на *Java*

```java
//package allukrainianOlimpiad;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str1 = scanner.next();
        scanner.close();

        ArrayList<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Character> str = new ArrayList<>();
        for (char i : str1.toCharArray()) {
            str.add(i);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < str.size(); i++) {
            if (str.get(i) == ')') {
                for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--) {
                    if (str.get(j) == '(') {
                        res.add(j + 1);
                        res.add(i + 1);

                        str.set(i, '@');
                        str.set(j, '@');
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(res.size() / 2);     
        for (int i = 0; i < res.size(); i += 2) {
            System.out.println(res.get(i) + " " + res.get(i + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

### Код на *Python*

```py
expression = list(input())
result = []

for i in range(len(expression)):
  if expression[i] == ')':

    for j in reversed(range(i)):
      if expression[j] == '(':
        result.append([j + 1, i + 1])
        expression[i] = expression[j] = '1'
        break

print(len(result))
for i in result:
  print(str(i[0]) + ' ' + str(i[1]))
```

### Проверка

[image: Проверка алгоритма]

---

### Вопрос

Почему алгоритм на Java справился намного быстрее чем на Python? И как можно это пофиксить?

Comment: Потому что у Java есть JIT-компилятор, а в стандартной реализации Python (CPython) его нет. Если сравнивать производительность Java машины и PyPy, то результаты скорее всего будут примерно одинаковые (по крайней мере сравнимые).

Comment: @insolor да, я это понимаю. Всегда при тестах Python был быстрее чем Java! Но почему-то здесь СОВСЕМ не так(( Я считаю, что это где-то ошибка в коде, но я не уверен

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ошибок в коде Python не вижу. Вижу медленный алгоритм, который при определённых условиях будет сильно отставать от оптимального. Java быстрее Python, поэтому решение на Java уложилось в установленное время, на Python же неоптимальность алгоритма проявилась.

Посмотрите сравнительные тесты [Java vs Python](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/python.html).

Я решил эту задачу на Python, используя быстрый алгоритм, который находит решение за один проход:

```
expression = input()
stack = []
result = ''
cnt = 0 
for idx, char in enumerate(expression, 1): 
    if char == '(':
        stack.append((idx,char))
    elif char == ')':
        if stack and stack[-1][1] == '(':
            result += f"{stack.pop()[0]} {idx}\n"
            cnt += 1

print(cnt)
print(result, end='')
```

**Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сравнил эти два алгоритма (мой и ваш) программой `time` на Linux, используя такое входное выражение:

```
expression = '(' * 100 + "4" + "+((7-4)+(4+4))*(7-4)" * 10000 + ')' * 100
```

**Результат:**

```
Мой = 0.08 с
Ваш = 1.727 с
```

Думаю, у них есть похожие тесты, поэтому ваше решение и не прошло.

Для интереса сравните время работы ваших решений на Java и Python с этим же выражением.

Comment: Я с Вами согласен, что алгоритм не оптимальный. Но алгоритм на Java "уложился " за 500мс, а на Python за 2с не смог. Почему Python так медленно сделал или Java так быстро?

Comment: @muryn.official А вы смотрели ссылку Java vs Python? В некоторых тестах Java в десятки раз быстрее. Можно сделать большое выражение (как в моём ответе), записать его в файл и потестить обе программы на нём. Увидим разницу в производительности конкретно для этой задачи. Я бы сам сделал, да с Java не знаком. Написаное понимаю, а сам на ней ничего не делал.

Comment: В Python при работе со списками, не рекомендуется использовать метод append.